# How to change textbox size(height) if text size increses?

Tags: html, css, textbox

I have value to show in input textbox in HTML. The value is address.
if address characters are more then i want to show whole text in the form of value of input textbox. Actually it shows the value correctly. But i want to see it in full text box.[Here, Address part shown. I want whole address in shown in this input text box.

My Code Is Like.

```
<tr>
<td class="tabth" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">Address</td> 
<td class="tabtd" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
    <input type="text" style="height:50px; overflow: auto;" name="address" value="502, Venus Atlantis, Nr. Shell Petrol Pump, Anandnahar-Prahladnagar Road, Ahmedabad,Gujarat, India............kkkkkkkkkkkkkk...........">
<‌​/td> 
<td>
<button type="submit" name="export" value="reg" class="btn btn-success pd">Save</button>
</td> 
</tr>
```

[Here is image of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqx2S.jpg)

Comment: Using `<input type="text">` it's not possible in HTML. So you'll have to use `<textarea>` .

Comment: Before posting your question you have to check whether any existing question is solving your problem or not. You are posting a duplicate question here.

Comment: sorry for the same question @Chirag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `textarea`
to show or get your long text values like that

```
<textarea  cols="40" rows="5" style="resize:none" name="address">
"502, Venus Atlantis, Nr. Shell Petrol Pump, Anandnahar-Prahladnagar Road, Ahmedabad,Gujarat, India"
</textarea>
```

`Cols` will change horizantal and `Rows` will change vertical length of input. Also you can use `ReadOnly=true` if you want to not implement an input but an output element instead of this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text to break into a new line, you need to use textarea (input text only allows one line of text)

```html
<textarea name="Text1" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
```